# Send StringList as Attachment via Email - Indy

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy10

How can I send whole StringList via attachment through Email without saving to the harddrive? I am aware of attachment limits..

Comment: Did you tried secondary TIdText ? You'd probably need setting CharSet to something like UTF-16 or UCS-2 and maybe it would wrap the lines around 80th character... But maybe it would "just work". TIdText is set to be made to send TStrings - so just try to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use TIdAttachmentMemory instead of TIdAttachmentFile :

```
StringList := TStringList.Create;
StringList.Append('foo');
StringList.Append('bar');

MemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
StringList.SaveToStream(MemoryStream);
MemoryStream.Position := 0;

IdMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
IdAttachmentMemory := TIdAttachmentMemory.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts,MemoryStream);
```

Comment: Instead of using a separate `TMemoryStream`, you can construct the `TIdAttachmentMemory` without any `CopyFrom` parameter value and then use its `OpenLoadStream()` method to get a `TStream` that you can pass to `SaveToStream()`. Alternatively, you can just pass the `StringList.Text` to the `TIdAttachmentMemory` constructor instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **StringList.Text** porperty. This property can be used to read and write and thus pass the content of a stringlist as a string paramater (instead of trying to pass an object).

Comment: I can't give you an example using email but basically you put your SenderStringList.Text into a string variable. Then you send that string via mail and the receiver creates a StringList and reads in the string (ReceiverStringList.Text := variable).

Comment: Yes but this question is about email attachment not how to put a stringlist text to a variable :)

Comment: Sorry :-) I thought you could solve your problem by attaching text to an email rather than attaching a StringList object.

Comment: @Richard - then use UUEncoder and just add it to the main body of message like UUE/XXE attachments must be. Though it is a bit less efficient than base64 attachements.

Answer (score 0):

Why not save it to file and send the file as an attachment?

Comment: Need to have access rights to the Hard Drive.. Adds complexity to your application... more effort for CPU :: old programmers had slow machines so every cycle counts :)

Comment: yes i do agree it is a lazy way to do it, but it would work, even though it is messy :-)